# Quelqu'un, quiconque, personne, n'importe qui?

Tags: pronoms, négation

I am trying to find the best way to translate: "We do not share your personal information with anyone."

So far, I have "Nous ne partageons vos informations personelles avec...".

Which ending best completes the sentence? avec quel qu'un, avec quiconque, avec personne, or avec n'importe qui?

I just need help finishing the sentence and I'm not sure which ending has the best meaning?

Comment: It would be useful to know what your context is here: legal, conversational, administrative, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either choose to say:

> Nous ne partageons vos informations personnelles avec personne.

or

> Nous ne partageons **pas** vos informations personnelles avec quiconque.

Answer (score 4):

The two right answers at the moment don't go into detail, so I'll add one more... You're looking for "the best meaning" so I'll associate the French phrases with their English translations:

> Nous ne partageons vos données personnelles avec **personne**.
>
> Nous ne partageons **pas** vos données personnelles avec **quiconque**.
>
> Nous ne partageons **pas** vos données personnelles avec **qui que ce soit**.

These all convey the strictest meaning: we don't share your info with a single entity. As Stéphane Gimenez writes, the latter two sound defensive rather than a neutral statement of policy.

> Nous ne partageons **pas** vos données personnelles avec **des tiers**.

This means we don't share your info with third parties. That probably makes the most sense in this context, as far as the legal meaning of the clause.

> Nous ne partageons **pas** vos données personnelles avec **n'importe qui**.

This means we don't share your info with "just anyone". We think carefully about who to share it with. Probably not the intended meaning!

Comment: I would add *...avec qui que ce soit* too.

Comment: @jlliagre What do you think of informations vs. renseignements or données ?

Comment: *Données personnelles* is the usual phrase.

Comment: Concering your last paragraph, “pas avec qui que ce soit” is close to “with absolutely nobody” and it isn't the same as “with just anyone” (in French, “avec n'importe qui”). These two last examples (“pas avec quiconque” and “pas avec qui que ce soit”) sound like defense against an accusation and don't fit well as statements of good behavior policies.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Thanks — updated the answer.

Comment: In legal texts in French, I often see: Nous ne partageons pas vos données avec des tiers. i.e. third parties. In non-legal contexts, the first three are what I'd say, and yes, the last two are defensive.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn the sentence on its head and make it sound more officialese

> - Les informations à caractère personnel ne font l'objet d'aucun partage.

If you want to inject the idea of *we*, you could say :

> - Les informations à caractère personnel ne font de notre part l'objet d'aucun partage.

If you want to further specify it with the idea of *anyone*, although it wouldn't add much to the meaning, you get

> - Les informations à caractère personnel ne font de notre part l'objet d'aucun partage avec qui que ce soit.